# AspectJ Decompilation

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have the following class:
    package ajia.messaging;

```
public class MessageCommunicator {
    public void deliver(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public void deliver(String person, String message) {
        System.out.println(person + ", " + message);
    }
}
```

And the following advice:

```
package ajia.security;
import ajia.messaging.MessageCommunicator;

public aspect SecurityAspect {
    private Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();

    pointcut secureAccess()
        : execution(* MessageCommunicator.deliver(..));

    before() : secureAccess() {
        System.out.println("Checking and authenticating user");
        authenticator.authenticate();
    }
}
```

I compile everything like this - `ajc -source 5 ajia\messaging\MessageCommunicator.java ajia\security\SecurityAspect.aj`

As I understand the resulting `MessageCommunicator.class` will already have aspect code included. I was wandering if standard java decompilers will decompile the class correctly?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Well, I just did, decompiled with JAD and it works indeed. Can see everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decompilers often work by recognizing the patterns produced by compilers. AspectJ tries to also produce code that follows the same kinds of pattern (the structure of byte code for catch blocks, that kind of thing). So usually the code will decompile ok unless some crazy weaving has gone on. The AspectJ project will accept bug reports on code that isn't cleanly decompilable and attempt to address it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works, at least with JAD decompiler

Comment: I suggest you either accept your own answer or just delete the whole question.